# What does the "000" argument in "=TEXT(RC[-1],""000"")" formula means and what is its use case?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to understand the meaning of "000" in the bellow expression:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""000"")"
```

I know the "TEXT" formula is used to store numbers as text, but I'm not sure what is the use case for this particular argument.

Comment: to add leading zeros? 1 -> 001, 10 -> 010, 128 -> 128 etc

Comment: OK that makes sense, but what if the cell value is a  mixture of digits and letters, for instance: "8A" or "14N"
Woud it make any difference at all or it would still apply the same rule?

Comment: If the cell value is a string (combination of number and alpha chars), it would make no difference. 8N  -> 8N

Comment: Thank you milo5m, this is exactly what I wasn't sure about. As I did my own tests,  but couldn't see any difference between the input and output values for strings.

Answer (score 0):

The "000" is the **format_text** variable in the **TEXT** function.

The text output of the function is padded with leading zeros.
It is applied to any blank or numeric **value** supplied to the function.
Blank values will have three zeros, single digit numbers will have two leading zeros and two digit numbers will have one leading zero added.
Numbers with three or more digits will not be modified.
Text values will not be modified.

[image]

Alternate formatting strings can be used, for example *"dd-mmmm-yyyy"* to format the input as a date.

Comment: Thank you, Robert, very informative answer! I wish I could vote it up, but I am afraid I do not yet have the necessary reputation.